# Find a particular solution of $y''-4y = 2e^{2x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I wanted to use the method of undetermined coefficients, why would a guess of $y_p = Ae^{2x}$ be incorrect?  In general, how can I avoid choosing incorrect guesses which initially seem to be correct?

Comment: Your $y_p$ is the solution to the homogeneous equation $y''-4y=0$.

Comment: So how can I change my guess to work around this?

Comment: Standard here is $Axe^{2x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take into consideration the characteristic polynomial of the homogeneous differential equation. In your case, the polynomial is
$$ p(\lambda) = \lambda^2 - 4 = 0. $$
The roots are $\lambda = \pm 2$. Since in your right hand side, you have the expression $Ce^{2x}$, and $2$ is a root of the characteristic equation, you need to modify your guess to be $y_p = Axe^{2x}$. More details can be found [here](http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/courses/Webcourse-contents/IIT-KANPUR/mathematics-2/node78.html).