# Using the method of undetermined coefficients, find an appropriate particular solution for $y'' + 25y = -x\sin(5x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'' + 25y = -x\sin(5x)$

Characteristic eq: $y'' + 25y = 0$

So we have:

$r^2+25 = 0$

$r = \pm 5i$

So the complementary solution takes the form:

$y_c = c_1\sin(5x)+c_2\cos(5x)$

So I thought a guess of:

$y_p = x(Ax+B)(C\sin(5x)+D\cos(5x))$

would be appropriate, but apparently it is not.  Can someone explain why, and the general methodology I can follow to solve similar problems?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%E2%80%B2%E2%80%B2%2B25y%3D%E2%88%92xsin(5x)) out

Comment: This doesn't really help me for the problem I'm having.

Comment: This is a situation very similar to that in your earlier question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229278/find-a-particular-solution-of-y-4y-2e2x --- did you learn anything from that?

Comment: Initially I would have guessed $y_p = (Ax+B)(C\sin(5x)+D\cos(5x))$, but since the characteristic eq has a sine and cosine term, I multiplied through by x.  Why is this wrong?

Comment: Anyone? Would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you obtain the general solution for the *homogeneous linear differential equation* $y'' + 25y = 0$, that is $$y_c = c_1\sin(5x)+c_2\cos(5x),$$ you can find the particular solution $y_p$ of $y'' +25y=−xsin(5x)$ by means of an *annihilating differential operator* for the function $x\sin{5x}$, which is in this case: $$ (D^2 + 25)^2 = D^4 + 50D^2 + 625 \quad \mbox{where  $D^n = \frac{d^n}{dx^n}$},$$ 
because (as you can check):
$$ (D^2 + 25)^2 (x\sin(5x)) = 0 \quad \forall \; x \in \mathbb{R}. $$

Thus, your *non-homogeneous linear differential equation*, that can be rewritten as $(D^2 + 25)y=-x\sin(5x)$, by application of the differential operator $(D^2 + 25)^2$ to both sides it's converted to an homogeneous linear differential equation  $(D^2 + 25)^3 y=0$. For this equation the general solution is:
$$ y = c_1 \cos(5x) + c_2 \sin(5x) + c_3 x\cos(5x) + c_4 x\sin(5x) + c_5 x^2 \cos(5x) + c_6 x^2 \sin(5x).$$
So, identifying $y_c$ in $y$ you get (because $y = y_c + y_p$) that:
$$ y_p = c_3 x\cos(5x) + c_4 x\sin(5x) + c_5 x^2 \cos(5x) + c_6 x^2 \sin(5x)$$
and evaluating in the original non-homogeneous linear differential equation you find the coefficients $c_3, c_4, c_5$ and $c_6$ (using the *method of undetermined coefficients* precisely).

Comment: @user1038665: Wasn't helpful this answer to you? That method allows you to find a particular solution without guess! Don't hesitate to ask anything if you wish.